# problem with installing splitstackshape package

Tags: r

I am trying to install splitstackshape for dataset stratification.

However, when I input the command, it reads

"unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1:
cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES'"

I looked up how to resove this, and the best answer I could find was to make sure that Xcode Command Line Tools is installed, using the input "xcode-select --install", which unfortunately returned "Error in install.packages : Unrecognized response “xcode-select --install”".

What should I do?

Comment: That URL doesn't work, so I'm not surprised. You will need to use the 4.2 or 4.3 packages folders instead, or find wherever the 4.1 has been archived to. See all the details for old packages for Mac elsewhere at this page: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

1. Update your R version. You can download the latest version from CRAN and install. (You don't need to uninstall old version on Mac.)
2. Install the package from CRAN.
3. If the error still persists, you may need to install X-code and command line tools. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/installing-xcode-command-line-tools).